# Blue box appearing instead of digital signature and signature panel contains unsigned signatures

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox, digital-signature, acrobat

## I am using pdfbox library for adding signature.

I am trying to attach digital signature in pdf and verifying it with **Notarius Certificate Authority**.when I try to attach certificate in pdf, and open it in the adobe acrobat, I am getting blue box appearing on the screen instead of signature image. Also if I open the signature panel of this pdf then it indicated that pdf is certified but it contains three unsigned signature fields (as we have three signatures in the pdf). What should be the reason  for getting the blue box?
I want my signatures to visible in adobe acrobat pdf reader with verified status.

Here are some images attached for your reference.
[Signed pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmglE.png)
[Signature panel for the same signed pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPBdv.png)

[please download signed pdf and open in in adobe acrobat](https://jumpshare.com/s/JKuo2Rm9yWKZakRBhW1w)

I have given the code that is used to insert sign into the pdf.

```
    private void addSignatureField(PdfField pdfField,PDDocument document,PDAcroForm pdfForm,File signImage,PrintLocation printLocation) throws Exception
   {
      PDRectangle rectangle = signatureFieldRectangle(document.getPage(0),pdfField,printLocation);
      PDPage pdPage = document.getPage(pdfField.getPage());
      List<PDField> pdfFormFields = pdfForm.getFields();
      PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(pdfForm);
      signatureField.setPartialName(pdfField.getName());
      PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
      pdfFormFields.add(signatureField);
      widget.setRectangle(rectangle);
      widget.setPage(pdPage);
      PDStream stream = new PDStream(document);
      PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(stream);
      form.setResources(new PDResources());
      form.setFormType(1);
      PDRectangle bbox = new PDRectangle(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
      form.setBBox(bbox);

      PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
      appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
      PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
      appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
      widget.setAppearance(appearance);

      try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document,appearanceStream))
      {
         cs.setNonStrokingColor(Color.white);
         cs.addRect(-5000, -5000, 10000, 10000);
         cs.fill();
         if (signImage != null) {
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
            cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(0.25f, 0.25f));
            PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension(signImage, document);
            cs.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            cs.restoreGraphicsState();
         }
      }
      pdPage.getAnnotations().add(widget);
      COSDictionary pageTreeObject = pdPage.getCOSObject();
      while (pageTreeObject != null) {
         pageTreeObject.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
         pageTreeObject = (COSDictionary) pageTreeObject.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PARENT);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please share the signed PDF for analysis. *" What should be the reason for getting the blue box?"* - by "blue box" do you mean the light blue ribbon on top saying "Certified by ..."? That's normal for signed PDFs, isn't it? *"it indicated that pdf is certified"* - Most likely your code has set MDP permissions (`SigUtils.setMDPPermission`); setting MDP permissions makes a signature a certification signature.

Comment: @mkl, Thanks for your response, It's not about blue ribbon on the top. I am talking about Three boxes that are appearing under that blue ribbon .These three boxes are the three signatures that I have added in pdf.

Comment: @mkl, I have attached the signed pdf.

Comment: The 3 boxes are unsigned signature fields. They contain a signature image (which is highly misleading) but not an electronic signature, i.e. a signature that uses a secret password to confirm a cryptographic checksum of the file (somewhat simplified explanation).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for your response, So should I remove these signature fields?
Our goal is to add signatures in pdf and at last we want to certify document by adding notarius certificate.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your response, this file is signed by all three users. No signature is remaining.

Comment: The three fields shouldn't have been added in the first place. From what I see, the original file was incrementally modified with 1 real electronic signature (with an empty appearance, which is legal) and 3 pseudo signatures. Really weird. The question is: what were you trying to do? I three more electronic signatures were needed, then empty fields should have been added and then the three users should have signed these fields e.g. with their PKI card.

Comment: @Deep It took me quite some of the comments here to understand what you actually want to achieve. At least I hope I've understood. See my answer.

Comment: What I am trying to do is adding signatures and verifying it with certificate. 
And for that first of all I am adding all the signature images with the method "addSignatureField" mentioned in the code. And after that I attach the notarius certificate to make it certified.certificate will add an invisible signature to pdf.

continue in the next comment.

Comment: In addSignatureField method, I am trying to get a list of PDField from PDAcroForm. After that I am adding a PDSignature field to this list. And I get a widget from this signature field. Then I draw the image with PDContentStream and add the widget in the document. And because of this signature field I am getting the unsigned signature fields in the signed pdf as shown in attached pdf and screenshots.


continue in the next comment.

Comment: If I remove the PDSignature field and try then the signature image will not be visible in the pdf page.

Also, I have to do these operations related to the PDAcroForm because, If I try to sign the pdf which is already sign, then it will detect the signature and warn me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments you appear to try to implement something akin to the regular workflow of Adobe Acrobat Sign: All the "signer" users supply some ink signature image and only the signing service applies an actual digital signature.

Your implementation puts those ink signature images into the PDF using signature fields and finally adds the only actual digital signature as an author signature.

#### The error

The error in your approach is that you use actual signature form fields for the ink signature images. Signature form fields are made for digital signatures (and timestamps), not for simple electronic signatures.

Your signature fields with the ink signature images do have visualizations (showing the images) but they don't have values (which would have to be signature dictionaries with CMS signature containers). Thus, Acrobat (like other software products, too) assumes those signature fields are not yet signed.

Now Acrobat has the feature (or quirk?) to display un-signed signature fields in a blue-ish color with a red "Signe Here" arrow and ignores the existing appearance.

This explains that you see

[image: screen shot]

Other viewers may handle this differently. The built-in viewer in Chrome, for example, shows your ink signature images:

[image: screen shot]

#### A fix

As a fix just don't use signature fields for simple electronic signatures, only for digital signatures.

Alternative options for showing those ink signature images include:

- adding those images to the static page content;
- adding those images as appearances of some generic, non-widget annotation;
- adding those images as appearances of (inactive) buttons.

Considering your wish, though...

> I want my signatures to visible in adobe acrobat pdf reader with verified status.

Those three simple electronic signatures cannot be verified because they are no digital signatures. Thus, the fix will remove them completely from the signature panel.

Comment: I understand your point. Now I have tried two ways to add images. 

1) Without adding a widget in the annotation of the page. And this is the code- 
    [https://ctxt.io/2/AACIMdk2EQ] 
    In this, I am not using a widget but I am having some problems.
    a) images are inverted when it is added to the page.
    b) image size and coordinates varying for different PDFs. (Here for different pdf I 
         have calculated the different coordinates x and y).

continue in the next comment.

Comment: 2) Using widget.
    I found out that PDSignature is adding COSName.FT as a key and COSName.SIG as 
    value in COSDictionary of the widget. (I have also tried to do it externally without 
    PDSignature, It's the same). 
    I have tried other COSNames like BBOX, IMAGE, RECT but problem in it is that when I 
    pdf open in browsers sign image is visible in adobe acrobate it is not visible.

So can You help me out in above options?

Comment: @DeepMorker *"images are inverted when it is added to the page"* - unfortunately you didn't provide the PDF and PNG, so I ran your code with files I have. I could not observe an image inversion. *"image size and coordinates varying for different PDFs."* - but that's true for any approach, isn't it?